# Сравнение данных разных типов в python2

Tags: python, python-2.x

Никак не могу найти информацию по каким правилам сравниваются (>, <) разные типы данных?

Почему сравнении при списка `b = [10, 0]`, числа `a = 5` и строки `s = 'sad'` получается

```
a > b   # False
s > b   # True
```

Т.е.

```
5 > [10, 0]      # False
'sad' > [10, 0]  # True
```

Как сравниваются такие типы данных?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int

> CPython implementation detail: Objects of different types except
>   numbers are ordered by their type names; objects of the same types
>   that don’t support proper comparison are ordered by their address.

Перевод: "Деталь реализации CPython: объекты разных типов, за исключением чисел, упорядочиваются согласно их **именам типов**, объекты одного типа, не поддерживающего операцию сравнения, упорядочиваются по адресу."

Ссылка на официальное руководство: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons
Цитата оттуда (перевод мой):

> Объекты различных типов, кроме различных числовых типов и различных
>   типов строк, никогда не равны; такие объекты
>   упорядочиваются последовательно, но произвольно (так что сортировка
>   неоднородного массива дает последовательный результат). Кроме того,
>   некоторые типы (например, файловые объекты) поддерживают только
>   вырожденное понятие сравнения, где любые два объекта этого типа не
>   равны. Опять же, такие объекты упорядочены произвольно, но последовательно.Операторы  <,
>   <=,> И> = вызовут исключение TypeError, когда любой операнд
>   является комплексным числом

В данной цитате слово "последовательно" - буквальный перевод слова "consistently", ИМХО, имеется в виду, что `sort([1, "", []])` всегда даст один и тот же результат.

---

Например:

```
5 < [] # -> True, т.к. 'int' < 'list'
[] < "" # -> True, т.к. 'list' < 'str
```

Comment: `s/дает последовательный результат/даёт совместимый результат/` (consistent)

Comment: можно ещё примеры из вопроса явно объяснить (`5 < []` потому что `type(5) == int` и `type([]) == list` и `'int' < 'list'`)

Comment: @jfs, я думаю, лучшим вариантом перевода слова *consistent* тут будет *стойкий* - в смысле однозначный. Честно говоря, переводил гуглом с небольшими правками, с этим словом не пришел к однозначному варианту.

Comment: 1- результаты могут разниться (если больше одного объекта несравнимого типа) между разными процессами -- никто не гарантирует те же адреса 2- относительный порядок в одном и том же процессе сохраняется (адрес объекта в Питоне не меняется) (если в одном списке `a < b`, то и в другом списке `a  < b` -- в этом смысле результаты consistent (непротиворечивые, совместимые)).